# Proper way to implement transactional HOTP?

Tags: transactions, finance, one-time-password, google-2fa

I am working on an Wallet Application, and we need to implement advanced-OTP to comply with the regulators.
We decided to go with HOTP (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) but it isn't enough because we have to tie generated OTP with each transfer transaction.
Do we have a standard way for this?
I'm thinking about doing the same as HOTP and adjust timestamp by mixing it with transaction_code (e.g timestamp + transaction_code).
Is it acceptable? Any solutions, opinions on this matter is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.